# read output of shell script in ANT Java task

Tags: java, ant, installation

I'll appreciate any help .

I created the shell script that collects servers IP - members of weblogic cluster to distribute some files across all servers in list.

I prepared a special ANT task for distribution and call this task from another shell script . Each time I call the ANT task I pass the next server IP to copy files on it.
This behaviour brings the installation structure.

Now I'd like to improve this behaviour . I want in ANT to read the output of the shell file to some list that I can loop thru from the ANT task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `outputproperty` attribute of the `exec` ant task. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html for the full documentation. With this, you can also handle standard error output.

Once the script output is in an ant property, you can iterate on it using [ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) foreach task [foreach task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html).

Comment: Thanks Tonio , Unfortunately I cannot use ant contrib

Comment: If you cannot use ant contrib, then you probably should roll your own custom ant task to do the job.